# Should I check for cookie existence right after setting it?

Tags: php, cookies

Using good development practices, should one check for the existence of the `setcookie` after setting it, or is it known to be set 100%?  Thank you.

```
<?php
    require "includes/settings.php";
    require "functions/php_function_library.php";

    $item_id = $_REQUEST['item_id'];
    $item_qty = $_REQUEST['quantity'];

    echo $item_id;
    echo $item_qty;

    $cookie_guid = guid();

    setcookie("anonymous_cart", $cookie_guid);

    #check that the cookie I just set exists?


    #insert new cart record into DB
    ...
?>
```

Comment: what happens if the browser is configured to deny cookies ...

Comment: The cookie won't actually exist on the client's machine until the request ends (i.e. after your PHP script terminates). This is because `setcookie()` using an HTTP header to set the cookie in the client's browser, and the client won't receive that information until the server sends the request back.

Comment: @cristi_b If they have cookies off they are probably not shopping online, so most likely not at an online store application.

Comment: @JoJo: Then you want to inform them that they cannot use the online store application. Instead of just having everything quietly "not work". Or do you not want your customers (who accidentally turned off cookies) to buy things from your shop?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Okay, I will do that. I will look for the best practice in doing that right after this task. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the return value, if false it failed. Otherwise you can consider it set (I've never seen it not get set in that case).

```
if(setcookie('anonymous_cart', $cookie_guid)){
    // Joy, cookie was set
}
```

However if the cookie being set is of critical importance, then checking it can't hurt (much).

**EDIT**

For those pointing out that this does not guarantee the cookie was *accepted*, I agree and did not say that it does (how could it? The client hasn't even received the cookie yet).  It simply means that the cookie was **set**.  Which is what op asked.

Comment: `setcookie`'s return value does not directly imply the cookie was accepted.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php  The function can run succesfully and still not have the value set.

Comment: @DeaconDesperado I didn't say it was.  It *will* return false if the cookie *could not be **set***.

Comment: It's a pretty commonly made mistake to rely on that return value in PHP to imply the presence on the value on the client.  I don't think its something we'd like to encourage.  I get your point that you didn't imply this... perhaps make an edit to reflect that?  Didn't downvote, btw.

Comment: @DeaconDesperado It may very well be a commonly made mistake to misinterpret the documentation, but I wholeheartedly disagree that checking the return value isn't something we should encourage.  On the contrary, *not* checking the return value is a critical programming oversight.

Comment: Perhaps I should be more clear... I meant relying on that return value to imply the value on the client.  You should of course check that it succeeeded, that is more or less implied in the docs, but relying on this to infer the client saved the value would be an oversight.

Comment: @DeaconDesperado Making that assumption would simply be wrong, yes.  Again though, that's not what op asked and not what my answer was addressing. But thank you for clarifying.

Comment: I see your point - I consider for the purposes of OP's question the greater issue is that check can't even be performed where he/she was trying.  Glad you got the votes back.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to check to make sure it exists right after you set it, but it is best practice to check to make sure it exists right before you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are inherently unreliable given their dependency on localized browser settings.

Make sure you have valid handling in place in case the value cannot be retrieved from the client when your scripts look for it.  In some cases this may even entail instructing the user  in the frontend to enable the cookies or add your domain to their excepted secure sites list, especially since what you appear to be implementing is a shopping system.

Check `setcookies`'s return value intially to make sure your server could send the value, but don't directly rely on this as implying the cookie was accepted.  Always check for presence of the value using `isset` or `array_key_exists` on the cookie global at the point you need to use the value.

Comment: Thank you. I believe this answer will help me most.